# Vim replace a range of numbers

Tags: vim

Is it possible in vim to replace `1-10` with `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`?

And I'm not talking `:s:1-10:1,23,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` I mean like a command that will look at the range and replace it appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
:%s/\(\d\+\)-\(\d\+\)/\=join(range(submatch(1),submatch(2)),',')/g
```

Of course, you may want to put it inside a user-defined command:

```
 :command! -nargs=0 RangeReplace %s/\(\d\+\)-\(\d\+\)/\=join(range(submatch(1),submatch(2)),',')/g
```

Comment: Excellent. I need to learn these things, but excellent. I'll just keep coming here for answers.

Comment: The key take-away here I think is the `\=` documented at `:help sub-replace-expression`